# Trouble logging in to website using python requests module

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm trying to login to the Starbucks website (login url: https://app.starbucks.com/account/signin?ReturnUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fapp.starbucks.com%2Fprofile) with no success.

I used the firefox inspect tool to find out the url i am supposed to send a POST request to and how should the payload data look like and i found out that the request url is "https://www.starbucks.com/bff/account/signin" and the payload is something like : "{"username": "my_username","password":"my_password"}, so here's my code:

```
import requests 

url = 'https://www.starbucks.com/bff/account/signin'
uname = "my_username"
pwd = "my_password"

payload = {"username":uname, "password":pwd}
with requests.Session() as s: 
    p = s.post(url,data=payload)
    print(p.status_code)
```

The status_code that is printed is always 200, which is strange because whenever i type invalid credentials manually, on the network tab of the inspect tool i get a 400 response code. And also, whenever i do print(p.content) instead of printing the status code, the content is always the same (both for wrong and correct credentials).

Can somebody help me out? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: The payload looks like JSON, try sending the data as JSON

Comment: @IainShelvington tried both with s.post(url,data=json.dumps(payload)) a nd it is still showing the same behaviour

Comment: use [Starbucks API](https://portal.starbucks.com/)